# QSlider event on changing minimum, maximum or range

Tags: c++, qt, qslider

Is there any way to catch event when QSlider minimum, maximum or range is changed? Like if `setMaximum()`, `setMinimum()` and `setRange()` were Qt signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can connect to the [rangeChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#rangeChanged) signal.